# Local DNS Server Refuses to Ask itself for DNS

Tags: debian, dns, routing, bind

I am running Debian 7 and have set up a DHCP and DNS server.

Everything is working nicely, except for the server itself not following the DNS entries in BIND.

The problem is that `/etc/resolv.conf` is populated by an upstream gateway as its primary DNS.  After manually changing the entry to point to itself instead of the upstream gateway, the DNS server uses the BIND settings before requesting DNS from the gateway.

Unfortunately, upon reboot or re-connect of the interface, `/etc/resolv.conf` reverts back to using the gateway, putting me back into the problematic situation.

I'd like to keep dynamic IP on that interface, while using a static nameserver.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following line to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` on your server:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

This makes it prepend `127.0.0.1` to whatever content of `/etc/resolv.conf` was forced on it by the gateway DHCP.

**Why `option domain-name-servers x.x.x.x` doesn't work**

From the `dhclient.conf(5)` man page:

> The option statement is used to specify the value of an option supplied
>      by  the  server,  or,  in  the  case  of  predefined leases declared in
>      dhclient.conf, the value that the user wishes the client  configuration
>      script to use if the predefined lease is used.

Comment: I set `option domain-name-servers x.x.x.x` thinking that would do it.  What'd the difference between 'option' and 'prepend'?

Comment: @earthmeLon Please see the updated answer.