# Can I set my Debian box to use OpenDNS nameservers if it uses DHCP?

Tags: debian, networking, dns, dhcp

I have a Debian box with this in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid NetworkName
    wpa-psk NetworkPass
```

and this in /etc/resolv.conf (presumably this stuff gets pulled from my Cisco router automatically?)

```
domain cable.myisp.com
search cable.myisp.com
nameserver isp_nameserver_ip1
nameserver isp_nameserver_ip2
```

I'd like to use OpenDNS (or Norton Secure DNS, basically just some other DNS server), so can I just remove the first two lines from /etc/resolv.conf and update the last two with new nameserver IP addresses? Is there anything else I'd need to do?

I can change the settings on my router easy enough but is it possible to do this within the OS?

Answer (score 3):

[This site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/) suggests you can put

```
option domain-name-servers x.y.z.1 x.y.z.2
```

into `dhclient.conf`.  This will prevent dhclient from clobbering resolve.conf with your dhcp provided nameservers.

Personally I take the route you mention and tell my dhcp server on the router to provide the nameservers I want that way all of my machines get the benefit and not just one server.

Comment: Hmmmm ok. One of the systems I'm thinking about doing this on is a personal laptop (also Debian), so would changing the DNS servers on that machine allow me to use those DNS servers even on other networks? I plan to change the DNS servers on my home router too so my server (as well as my other machines) can take advantage of it.

Comment: If you put that line in `dhclient.conf` it will use those DNS servers so matter where you are; it is a hard override of dhcp provided nameservers. If you want to only use them on specific networks you probably need to use the hooks in the site I linked.

Comment: That link says that "Also, many corporates block snooping name server such as OpenDNS due to privacy issues." Is that something I should worry about? (That's probably a separate question though, but what does it mean for the DNS nameserver to be snooping?)

Comment: I'm not sure what it is talking about there. If you (and you most certainly should be able to) can send to and receive from UDP/53 you should be able to use any nameservers. I'm not familiar with OpenDNS so I can't comment on any extra issues that might introduce.

Comment: I may not be able to do this on my router; in the setup screen it lists the DNS servers, but there isnt an option to change them. It just says "domain name" then lists something from my ISP, and the DNS servers under that. I guess thats because the router is pulling them right from the modem.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dhclient.conf`, you can prepend or append alternative DNS servers to the ones provided by your DHCP. The pertinent options are

```
prepend domain-name-servers x.x.x.x;
```

and

```
append domain-name-servers x.x.x.x;
```

You can prepend/append as many space-separated addresses as you like to the list.
See my answer to a similar question titled [Local DNS Server Refuses to Ask itself for DNS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99149/26909)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post I wrote a while ago, titled: [How to Override DHCP Settings on a Fedora/CentOS/RHEL Linux Box](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/6194/how-to-override-dhcp-settings-on-a-fedoracentosrhel-linux-box/).

There are 2 methods that I'm aware of where you can "append" your own DNS servers to the list provided by the DHCP server.

#### Method #1 - /etc/dhclient.conf

This first way is probably the most direct. The app, `dhclient` can make use of a config. file, `/etc/dhclient.conf`. To override the contents of the `/etc/resolv.conf` file simply create the file `/etc/dhclient.conf`:

```
interface "eth0" {
   supersede domain-name "local.home";
   supersede domain-name-servers 192.168.0.5, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
   request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name;
   require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
   script "/sbin/dhclient-script";
}
```

This will result in the following `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search local.home
nameserver 192.168.0.5
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

#### Method #2 - disable DNS propagation

The second approach is to disable dhclient’s ability to create the file `/etc/resolv.conf` in the first place. This makes use of another dhclient facility, called hooks. Specifically there are 2 hooks, enter & an exit hook. To disable the creation of `/etc/resolv.conf`, you can create a file called: `/etc/dhclient-enter-hooks`. The contents should be as follows:

```
make_resolv_conf() {
        # We don't want /etc/resolv.conf changed
        # So this is an empty function
        return 0
}
```

Make the file `dhclient-enter-hooks` executable:

```
$ chmod +x /etc/dhclient-enter-hooks
```

Additionally you’ll want to manually create a `/etc/resolv.conf` file, just like the one above. Doing it this way you’ll be creating a static `/etc/resolv.conf` file that won’t get rewritten each time the DHCP lease is renewed and/or changes in any way.

#### References

- [vacmf.org how-to-prevent-dhcp-server-to-override-your-resolvconf-script](http://vacmf.org/2006/12/20/how-to-prevent-dhcp-server-to-override-your-resolvconf-script/)
- [freebsd.org forums thread](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=15283)
- [ubuntuforumns.org thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-369907.html)
- [calomel.org dhclient article](https://calomel.org/dhclient.html)

Comment: On my system, `dhclient.conf` is located at `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. Is that the right file?

Comment: @MGreene - yes that's the correct file. Different distros organize configuration files differently.